How to retrieve automatic values from the Y-axis in the recharts library?
The domain parameter is responsible for generating values on the Y-axis. If expenses are added, the axis generates 5 points (tickCount={5}) from 0 to the "auto" value, which returns an automatically generated value from the library.
Here is my question: how can I retrieve the highest value among the generated values on the Y-axis?
<YAxis
   dataKey="totalExpenses"
   orientation="right"
   type="number"
   tickCount={5}
   fontSize={10}
   fontWeight={500}
   width={40}
   domain={noExpenses || noData ? [0, 120] : [0, "auto"]}
/>


What I need to achieve is, for example, as shown in the sample image, I need to retrieve the value 600, which is the highest value from the Y-axis that was automatically generated in the YAxis component.
